# kivy: The module raised an important error: "Couldn't find matching GLX visual"

Tags: python, kivy, beagleboneblack, vnc-server, glx

I have Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) installed on the beaglebone back. I am connected to my beaglebone black through a vnc session like this:

On Beaglebone: vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24

Here is the Xorg config on beagle bone: 
    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Builtin Default Monitor"
    EndSection

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Builtin Default fbdev Device 0"
    Driver          "modesetting"
    Option          "HWcursor"      "false"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Builtin Default fbdev Screen 0"
    Device          "Builtin Default fbdev Device 0"
    Monitor         "Builtin Default Monitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option          "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier      "Builtin Default Layout"
    Screen          "Builtin Default fbdev Screen 0"
EndSection


Section "Module"
    Load            "extmod"
    Load            "glx"
EndSection
```

When I run my kivy program I get the following message:

```
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.7.2
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/ubuntu/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-02-15_24.txt
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 144 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img_gif (img_pil ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <./setupmyprogram.kv>
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[WARNING] [WinPygame   ] Video: failed (multisamples=2)
[WARNING] [WinPygame   ] trying without antialiasing
[ERROR  ] [Window      ] Unable to use pygame
[ERROR  ] [Window      ] The module raised an important error: "Couldn't find matching GLX visual"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./setupmyprogram.py", line 55, in <module>
     SetupMyProgramAPP().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 576, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.options.get('kv_file'))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 399, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(filename)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1323, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1384, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 151, in __init__
     EventLoop.ensure_window()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 111, in ensure_window
     import kivy.core.window
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 983, in <module>
     ), True)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
     cls = cls()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 468, in __init__
     self.create_window()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 128, in create_window
     raise CoreCriticalException(e.message)
 kivy.core.CoreCriticalException: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.7.2
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/ubuntu/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-02-15_25.txt
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 144 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img_gif (img_pil ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <./myapplication.kv>
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[WARNING] [WinPygame   ] Video: failed (multisamples=2)
[WARNING] [WinPygame   ] trying without antialiasing
[ERROR  ] [Window      ] Unable to use pygame
[ERROR  ] [Window      ] The module raised an important error: "Couldn't find matching GLX visual"
 Exception kivy.core.CoreCriticalException: CoreCriticalException("Couldn't find matching GLX visual",) in 'kivy.properties.dpi2px' ignored
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[WARNING] [WinPygame   ] SDL wrapper failed to import!
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <sdl> (import error)
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <x11> (import error)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I cant figure out why I am getting the error [ERROR  ] [Window      ] Unable to use pygame
    [ERROR  ] [Window      ] The module raised an important error: "Couldn't find matching GLX visual"

Is this because I am running though vncserver? or am I missing something (libs/modules) in my 
beagleboard.

I have the following installed:  libgl1-mesa-glx:armhf libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni libxcb-glx0:armhf libva-glx1:armhf  libqt5opengl5:armhf

Also when I do the following I get the same error about GLX visual:

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 12 2014, 08:42:26) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.display.init()
>>> pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.OPENGL|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pygame.error: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
>>> 
>>> pygame.version.ver
'1.9.1release'
>>>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE: Stackexchange wont let me answer my own question ... so updating my question with the solution:**

I found the issue. vncserver does not give you gl capabilities, use x11vnc instead.

x11vnc -display :0 -forever -bg -repeat -nowf

I am not using a password file, and it will complain about this... but now I can vnc to my beagleboard and run kivy application with GL.

Answer (score 3):

Answered by author himself:

> I found the issue. vncserver does not give you gl capabilities, use x11vnc instead.

```
x11vnc -display :0 -forever -bg -repeat -nowf
```

> I am not using a password file, and it will complain about this... but now I can vnc to my beagleboard and run kivy application with GL.